# Error al compilarr java en atom

Tags: java, atom-editor, java-18

En mi proyecto, tengo varias carpetas y a la hora de compilar el programa principal me da un erro de NOTCLASSFOUND pero eso solo me pasa si dentro del archivo introduzco Ej: package vista; pero si lo ejecuto sin esa linea no me da el error he probado a hacerlo en el simbolo del sistema y si me deja compilar nose donde puedo estar el error, el plugin que utilizo es basic-java-compile. En las variables de entorno tengo agregado JAVA_HOME con la ruta de jdk y luego en la path tengo agregado %JAVA_HOME%.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nose que es lo que puede estar mal, una ayuda porfavor

Comment: como usas java 18 debes de crearte modulos, a este sistema se le llama jigsaw

Comment: aprender a [ask], el codigo no se sube en imagenes